# Difference between parlando and parlante

Tags: verbs, difference, vocabulary

What is the difference between

*parlando* and *parlante*

*credendo* and *credente*

and

*dante* and *dando*

and many others.

Are they the same thing? Does parlando and parlante both mean speaking, does it matter which one you use?

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't going to distinguish them if you to translate to English word-by-word, because they both translate to "speaking". Some understanding of grammar / sentence construction is necessary.

**Parlante** works as an adjective, can be inflected normally (plural *parlanti*), and means "that is speaking / that speaks":

*il grillo parlante* -> *the speaking cricket; the cricket who can speak*.

**Parlando** has the grammatical function of a verb, and only appears in a few very specific constructions; the most common is the translation of the present continuous

*Giovanni sta parlando* -> *Giovanni is speaking*.

but it can also appear as the main verb of a subordinate

*We spent the night speaking about football* -> *Abbiamo trascorso la notte parlando di calcio*.

Comment: So you could use parlando to say something like speaking of which as --- parlando di quale

Comment: @WolvesEyes Yes, *parlando del quale*. More common, though, is the expression *a questo proposito*.

Comment: Interesting, still have a lot to learn, with all the conjugations, you can form the same sentence in a lot more different combinations then English,.